# How to correct the scope of a variable that is created within a do-while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, scope, do-while

I am struggling to get the correct scope for my variable "input".

I am making a calculator for a university task, and I've got everything working apart from when I tried to make it loop by wrapping my main code in a do-while loop. Because the variable "input" is declared in the "do" part of the loop, it didn't know what it was when I was trying to use it in the "while" condition. To fix this I then declared "input" as a string before my do-while loop to make it a global. However, now the scanner that takes the value of input will not work.
AM I doing something stupid or am I missing something?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        String input;

        do {

            System.out.println("Welcome to the calculator. Please enter an operator (+, -, /, *) below:");

            Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String oper = myScanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Now please enter two numbers:");
            double a = myScanner.nextDouble();
            double b = myScanner.nextDouble();

            switch (oper) {
            case "+" :
                System.out.println(CalculatorUtils.add(a, b));
                break;
            case "-" :
                System.out.println(CalculatorUtils.subtract(a, b));
                break;
            case "/" :
                System.out.println(CalculatorUtils.divide(a, b));
                break;
            case "*" :
                System.out.println(CalculatorUtils.multiply(a, b));
                break;
            }

        System.out.println("Do you want to complete another calculation? (y/n)");
        input = myScanner.nextLine();


        }
        while (input.contentEquals("y"));

    }


}
```

I expect this to be the output:
Welcome to the calculator. Please enter an operator (+, -, /, *) below:
+
Now please enter two numbers:
32.5
12.5
45.0
Do you want to complete another calculation? (y/n)
y
(This is where the code would start again)

However I'm not being able to enter my input when being asked if I would like to do another calculation.

Comment: What do you mean by "not being able to enter my input"? Are your keypresses not recorded on the terminal?

Comment: What do you mean by 'correct the scope'? There is no scope problem here that needs correcting.

Comment: @AndrewMcDowell that wouldn't help. The `input` is read before the `while`, so it should work correctly. It's unclear what "not able to enter input" means actually here.

Comment: @Kayaman I think he wants to say the program is getting exited before being asked for "do another calculation".

Comment: @Kayaman Good point, not paying enough attention.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. Currently when I ask the user if they want to complete another calculation, it will not let the user enter anything. It is as if I haven't put the line:
input = myScanner.nextLine();

Comment: @Kayaman Yes that is the case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: @KevinAnderson I think you are correct after looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input;

        do {

            System.out.println("Welcome to the calculator. Please enter an operator (+, -, /, *) below:");

            Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String oper = myScanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Now please enter two numbers:");
            double a = myScanner.nextDouble();
            double b = myScanner.nextDouble();

            switch (oper) {
                case "+":
                    System.out.println(CalculatorUtils.add(a, b));
                    break;
                case "-":
                    System.out.println(CalculatorUtils.subtract(a, b));
                    break;
                case "/":
                    System.out.println(CalculatorUtils.divide(a, b));
                    break;
                case "*":
                    System.out.println(CalculatorUtils.multiply(a, b));
                    break;
            }
            myScanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Do you want to complete another calculation? (y/n)");
            input = myScanner.nextLine();
myScanner.nextLine();


        }
        while (input.contentEquals("y"));

    }


}
```

It happens because second time you call `myScanner.nextLine()` it just scans <kbd>enter</kbd> from before. It will happen after `myScanner.nextDouble()` but not after `myScanner.nextLine()` because `myScanner.nextLine()` reads/scans until including next newLine character (`\n`) whereas myScanner.nextDouble() will just scan a double and leave.

[Here is similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 0):

What you *do not* want to do is create a `Scanner` on every trip around the loop.  Move the definition and initialization of your `Scanner` variable outside the loop:

```
    String input;
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the calculator. Please enter an operator (+, -, /, *) below:");

        String oper = myScanner.nextLine();

        // rest of loop...

    } while (input.contentEquals("y"));
```

This may or may not solve you're immediate problem, but it's still the right thing to do in general.

Comment: Thank you, I have moved it outside of the do-while loop. It hasn't solved my problem, but it had improved my best practise

Comment: I think you need to do `myScanner.nextLine()` after reading in the values of `a` and `b`.  The explanation for why is somewhat technical and tedious, but it should help.